# What is the General formula of gradient of $r^n$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, differentiation, vector-fields, calculus

so, the question is that **r** is the separation vector from a fixed point $(x',y',z')$ to the point $(x,y,z)$ and let $r$ be its length.

the answer to the question of what is the general formula of $$\nabla (r^n)$$ is $$ nr^{n-1} \hat{r}$$

How did you attain that answer? [I used the differentiation method but I'm not sure if I'm correct]

Comment: if r is the length of a vector (scalar) , so what is $~\hat r~$

Comment: Check [Power_rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules#The_polynomial_or_elementary_power_rule) of differentiation, there are many such rules.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the chain rule. Given functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $r:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ we can compose $f\circ r:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. In that case the chain rule states that $$\nabla[f\circ r](p)=f'(g(p))\nabla r(p),\quad \forall p\in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

In your case we have $f(t)=t^n$ and $r(p)$ the standard radius function, which in Cartesian coordinates is given by: $$r(x^1,\dots, x^n)=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x^i)^2}.$$ Given that $f'(t)=nt^{n-1}$ we have $f'(r(p))=nr(p)^{n-1}$ and so the derivative is $$\nabla[r^n](p)=nr(p)^{n-1}\nabla r(p).$$

Or omitting the point $p$ we have an equality of functions $$\nabla (r^n)=n r^{n-1}\nabla r.$$

Finally it is easy to show, either in Cartesian or spherical coordinates, $\nabla r = \hat{\mathbf{r}}=\frac{\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|}$ where $\mathbf{r}$ is the standard position vector so that we have $$\nabla(r^n)=nr^{n-1}\hat{\mathbf{r}}.$$